# Why T: Send for std::thread::spawn()

Tags: rust

[`std::thread::spawn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) is defined as (abbreviated)

```rust
fn spawn<F, T>(f: F) where F: FnOnce() -> T, T: Send {}
```

Why is the closure's **return** value required to be `Send`?

It is perfectly understandable why `F: Send`, as `F` will execute in a separate thread, and closing over any `!Send` would allow two threads to access data in an unsynchronized way; the obvious example here is `std::rc::Rc`, which can't be shared among threads due to it's implementation, and therefor can't be closed over in `F`.

Yet, things are different for the *return value* of `F`. As the closure returns a `T`, that `T` can (by definition) not be accessed by the spawned thread after the closure's return. Unlike when creating the thread, where the number of simultaneously running threads goes **up**, when returning from `F` the number of threads goes **down**. So where is the strict requirement for `T: Send` coming from, if the restrictions on `T` are by definition less severe on return than on spawn?

For instance, if the spawning thread holds onto a `Rc` while passing a clone to the spawned thread, unsound memory access would occur. But if the spawned thread owned a `Rc` while returning a clone of it, one of the `Rc` would be dropped *while still inside the closure*, while the other would be returned via the `JoinHandle`; there is no way for the spawned thread so come back from the dead and access that `Rc` again...

What I'm getting at is that there are mainly two reasons for things to be `Send`/`!Send`:

1. The Rust-specific implementation of `T` is only sound for `T: !Send`; this is the case of `Rc`, among others.
2. The underlying (possibly OS-specific) implementation is actually `!Send` by itself. Examples that I'm aware of are some mutex implementations, or sqlite3-objects under some configurations.

Is the requirement for `T: Send` motivated by caution, to allow for easier, sound implementations under reason (2)? Or are there other, Rust-specific, reasons why the *return value* of a thread needs to be `Send`?

Comment: But the `JoinHandle` moves back the returned value to the original thread. That is what `Send` semantic allows. The fact that your particular case of `Rc` might be sound even without that trait doesn't change the general case.

Comment: @rodrigo, I realize that this is what the implementation does. The question is why the "general case" **is** the general case.

Comment: I mean, `spawn` is a contract, and currently the only way to describe the requiremets of `T` is with `T: Send`. I think that some subtler trait has been proposed, meaning _this type can be sent to other thread, but only if the original one has lost all access to it_. That could be used for async work-stealing threaded runtimes, and maybe also for the `JoinHandle` argument. But nothing has come of it, yet.

Comment: What use would returning a value that can't be returned to the original thread be? Who would receive it? You can always trivially suppress returning anything with`;`

Answer (score 2):

The contract of `Send` is quite simple: the value is *always* safe to send to another thread.

In the case of `F` this is obvious; you are sending the data owned by the closure to the new thread.

In the case of the return value, the value is constructed *in the thread* and then returned back to the thread that owns the `JoinHandle`, so the same constraint applies.

Think of it like this: `F` is sent into the thread, and the return value is sent back out.  Therefore, both types must be `Send`.

Consider the case of a thread-bound resource that executes cleanup code in its `Drop` implementation.  Such a value would be `!Send` because it must be cleaned up inside of the same thread it was created from.  If you were to return such a value from a thread to another thread, the drop code would run in the wrong thread!

Rust is designed to be conservative: if it is permitted, then it is safe. [This does *not* mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent) if it is safe, then it is permitted!

If an `Rc<T>` has a strong reference count of 1, a weak reference count of 0, and `T: Send`, then it is safe to send to another thread.  However, the reference count is a runtime attribute (which cannot be evaluated at compile time) while traits are a compile-time concept (`dyn` notwithstanding).  Therefore, `Rc` is *never* `Send`, which does keep you from doing some sound things.  (You may be interested in [Sometimes-Send Values in Rust](https://blog.chrishowie.com/2023/06/06/sometimes-send-values-in-rust/) from my blog.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm perfectly aware that `Send` as a contract is what it is, and `Rc` is either `Send` or it isn't. What I'm trying to get at is that returning **from a thread** has different implications that sharing **to a thread**. To stick with the already overstretched `Rc`-example: Once `F` has returned, all strong and weak pointers have been dropped; the joined thread can't - under any circumstance - observe or change `T` at this point; the joining thread can't observe any action by the joined thread. So one might expect a less strict bound for `T` than for `F`.

Comment: @user2722968 That holds true for `Rc` but potentially not for other types. `Send` has nothing to do with sharing _directly;_ it has to do with _whether it's always safe for a value to cross a thread boundary._ Sharing is just _one_ such case where that can be problematic. A value returned from a thread very much does cross a thread boundary, so I'm still very confused why you would expect there to be an exception for that case. Perhaps there could be a trait like `ReturnFromThread` but its use would be quite limited.

Comment: @user2722968 In particular, it would be limited because returning a value from a thread is not something that's done a whole lot in production code. Typically you would be passing values between threads using channels, as "return a value from a thread" strongly implies that you have a thread per task, which is usually not ideal.

Comment: @user2722968 Even if we continue with the `Rc` example, your assessment is incomplete. An `Rc` may be stored in a `thread_local!` which when dropped would be after the value is returned from the thread. Thus you could have multiple `Rc`s handling the same value from two different threads (one returned and one in thread local storage) -> UB waiting to happen.